# Regex to find pattern, return subpattern

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 var s = "lala url(ok) tee hee url( oh ya ) kk";
 s.match( /url(([^)]+))/g );
```

From 's' I am trying to extract:

```
 ['ok', ' oh ya ']
```

but, getting:

```
 ["url(ok", "url( oh ya "]
```

I can iterate over that list and remove the 'url(', but I suspect some regex-fu can remove it too.

Comment: You seem to know that `(...)` denotes a capture group in a regular expression is not treated *literally*. Why did you think then that one of the two pairs in `url((...))` would be treated differently?

Answer (score 2):

in other language regex support lookbehind by using regex like this `(?<=url\()(([^)]+))`

But unfortunately javascript regex doesn't support lookbehind like [this example](http://regexr.com?35teq), so you must iterate it. Except you don't realy need that **url** word to be included.

Comment: True, but lookbehinds are not necessary to extract the desired information.

Comment: he need **url** behind the actual regex!

Comment: Sure, but a lookbehind is not necessary either way. One can use `regex.exec` (http://jsfiddle.net/B4kJf/). But maybe that's what you meant by "iterate it".

Comment: “You should use a lookbehind, but you can’t. Iterate” is not an answer.

Comment: @felix yes `next,for,foreach` are some kind of [iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration)

Comment: @minitech in the question he said "I suspect some regex-fu can remove it too". i answer it by(in other means) **"you must iterate it, because the regex you are looking for is called lookbehind, and that doesn't exist in javascript"** and i giving example too.

Comment: You gave an example of something that doesn’t work. Why not give an example of “iterating it”?

Comment: because he said "I can iterate over that list and remove the 'url(',". so i think he already know how to iterate. Instead, the other answer is just give example of what the questioner already know. Is that better? than letting questioner know about regex compatibility?

Comment: @Angga: No, I don’t think that one’s an answer, either. Felix Kling’s answer is actually *the* answer. (Sorry for the late reply — didn’t make it to my inbox.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape first set of parentheses as

```
 s.match( /url\(([^)]+)\)/g );
```

Please, note that `ok` and `oh ya` would be part of the capturing groups instead of matches directly.

You can retrieve the capturing groups as:

```
var str = "lala url(ok) tee hee url( oh ya ) kk",
    re = /\(([^)]+)\)/g, match ;

while( (match = re.exec( str )) !== null )
    console.log( match[0] + " : " + match[1] );

/* Prints:
   url(ok) : ok
   url( oh ya ) :  oh ya 
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Even after fixing the expression, when you use the `g` flag and `.match`, the values captured by the capture groups are not included in the result.

But you can still get what you want by using [`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```
var s = "lala url(ok) tee hee url( oh ya ) kk";
var pattern = /url\(([^)]+)\)/g;
var urls = [];
var match;
while(match = pattern.exec(s)) {
    // match is an array like ["url(ok)", "ok"]
    urls.push(result[1]);
}

// urls will be ["ok", " oh ya "]
```

In each iteration, `match` will be an array containing the full match as first element and the value of every capture group as further element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
s.match( /url(([^)]+))/g );
```

on:

```
s.match( /url\(([^)]+)\)/g );
```